# Get wrong profile picture size

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Why do I receive an image of 160*160 when i ask for an image of 99*67 with https://graph.facebook.com/552985295/picture?width=99&height=67

Answer (score 0, accepted):

160x160 is default or nearest, when given resolution is not supported